# iMacros character encoding issue

Tags: character-encoding, macros, web-scraping, imacros

I'm trying to scrape form a site, but iMacro doesn't load the page.
URL GOTO=http://www.grosshandel-produkte.com/adressen/detail/id/13500

On firefox 17 web console there is an error saying,

GET http://www.grosshandel-produkte.com/adressen/detail/id/13500 [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 598ms]

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Is there a way to enforce charset in iMacros? I tried changing browsers charsets. It didn't work either. The site is German. I tried utf-8, but didn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use smartsniff or Fiddler2 and navigate to the site normally, they will tell you what encoding etc to use when trying to load the site and identify the fault.

```
GET http://www.grosshandel-produkte.com/adressen/detail/id/13500 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.grosshandel-produkte.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: symfony=9pebil173uvj7j4r61ntbu3072; __utma=21097197.1518127093.1358333525.1358333525.1358333525.1; __utmb=21097197.0.10.1358333525; __utmc=21097197; __utmz=21097197.1358333525.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

The response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 16 Jan 2013 10:53:09 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
P3P: CP="ALL CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR BUS IND PHY UNI PUR COM NAV INT DEM"
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Chunked response :P